# c# and JavaScript

Tags: development, javascript

So i have this code

```
sb.AppendLine(  "var nameSplit = users[i].split('\');");
```

The sb.AppendLine is C# and the bit inside is JavaScript, I am trying to split users[i] so that I can strip out the Domain name, unfortunately this does not work I have also tried

```
sb.AppendLine(  "var nameSplit = users[i].split('\\');");
```

It doesn't make much sense really, I have done an alert of nameSplit and it shoes that it splits the text on every letter as though the \ escapes nothing, the second example doesnt work at all when I would expect that to and as javascript on its own it works fine.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
sb.AppendLine(  "var nameSplit = users[i].split('\\\\');");
```

this will give the javascript

```
var nameSplit = users[i].split('\\');
```

\ is an escape character in both C# and javascript so you need two of then in a litteral to specify that you need one in the real string.

Comment: Per I think I love you, genuinely haha.

Comment: P.s. yes it worked :D

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a '@' in front of the quote, so it would look like....

```
sb.AppendLine(  @"var nameSplit = users[i].split('\');");
```

The @ symbol should make the code take the string 'as is' and ignore special characters and whatnot.

Comment: Woopsy, Per Jakobsen is right, the above would need to be '\\' with the @, or '\\\\' without

Comment: Thanks Zork, I didn't try this one as Per's worked but I appreciate you taking the time to answer :)
Matt